# Orchard Custom Module Layout

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, orchardcms

I created a custom Module in Orchard and want to display some Data in a View now. Everything is working except that it doesn't use the Layout of my theme.

How can I use the current Theme Layout for my Custom Module/View?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are missing `[Themed]` attribute on your controller.

```
namespace FooBar.Controllers {
    [Themed]
    public class FooBarController : Controller {
```